# Proper layout for EditText Boxes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was wondering about what is wrong with my layout.
[Here](http://i49.tinypic.com/kd72f6.png) is a screenshot.

Problem being that the text is being cut off in edit text boxes.

I suppose there is something wrong with the text's XY co-ordinates at the time of typing in those edit text boxes; the cursor blinks fine to me.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/svqgq2D9) is the pastebin of my XML layout (not putting it here because its quite lengthy).

Any advice will be appreciated. 
 Thanks

Comment: you are fixing the height og your edit text `android:layout_height="30dp"` make it `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Thanks for replying fast. I have fixed its height as because the EditText box is quite large in height if compared to the TextView to the left of it. It was making it look weird, so had to fix its height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text size of the text inside edittext is large for hardcoded 30dp height of edittext. You can either set edittext height to wrapcontent or reduce the textsize of edittext (10-14sp)so that it fits inside.

It is advised by android to set minimum height of clickable area to at least 48dp.
http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: :D Looks like I forgot to set the "text's font size". Will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Marking your reply as the Answer :) Made me realize how absent minded I can become in editing XML. Thanks.